# How does the use case for sinonjs fake differ from spy or stub?

Tags: javascript, sinon

The sinon documentation for fakes states that "It simplifies and merges concepts from spies and stubs". The functionality appears the same as stubs and spies. Given this similarity, when should a fake be used instead of a stub or spy?